# Intel AC 7260 No Wireless Function on Linux Mint 17 with Kernel 4.2.0-35

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, intel, firmware, iwlwifi

My box is currently running **Mint 17 Qiana 64-bit with kernel 4.2.0-35**. The firmware I have available for this card are iwlwifi-7260-7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, and 17 (which is the latest that Intel says it will run with).  Previously, I was using the **ASUS PCE-AC68** card, but it would randomly drop connection for multiple minutes at a time due to crappy driver support from Broadcom.

Looking at *dmesg* output, the card complains if firmware 15 is not available, and refuses to load anything else. Having kernel 4.2+ means that backports won't do anything for me, but decided to try backports from **4.2-rc1-0** before realizing that.

Booting into recovery mode and attempting to enable networking just leads to the system stalling with the message **ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.wlan1**, which is weird because it should be on wlan0 anyways, unless I forgot something when disabling the ASUS card driver before swapping it out. It eventually times out and continues without networking. The same thing happens on normal boot, judging by the 90+ second long black screen I get before anything else happens.

Output of **modinfo iwlwifi | head** suggests that the firmware is either non-existant or not being loaded, even though I can see the ucode files in /lib/firmware.

Output of **rfkill list all**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

I do not have any other way to access internet with my desktop, though I am able to access internet with this laptop running Mint 17.2. How do I get wireless access back without having to resort to buying another wireless card?

**Edit:** I also get the message "**VBoxClient: the VirtualBox kernel is not running. Exiting.**" after login. I uninstalled VirtualBox and still get the same notice, but I figured it was related since it didn't show up until I upgraded my kernel and changed my wireless card.

Comment: What is the question? Which distro supports the AC 7260? What hardware should I buy that is supported by Mint 17? Where can I find firmware 15? Please edit your post and include a real question ( correct sentence with a question mark, that cannot be answered with *Yes* or *No* )

Comment: @Anthon Added the question.

Comment: Much better to be explicit, than to let people guess ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that all I needed to do was change my Wireless Interface preference in Wicd (never had luck with standard Network Manager). Not exactly something I realized needed to be changed.